# Isn’t a word missing?

Tags: errors

I’m　quoting a part of the article titled “Pakistan Sees Shared Intelligence Lapse” written by Alan Cowell in today’s (May 4) New York Time’s Asia Pacific section (online edition) simply by cut-and-pasting of the text:

> “After the meeting, Mr. Gilani that he
>   did not believe the United States
>   Congress would show its displeasure
>   with Pakistan by cutting aid to his
>   nuclear-armed nation and he said the
>   West would continue to support
>   Pakistan as a “responsible nation.”
>   “We are working together” against
>   terrorism, he said.

Don’t we need ‘said’ or ‘told’ between Gilani and that in the first line, or omission of the verb permitted in press English, or it is simply erroneous drop of ‘said’?

Comment: Since you are quoting it, I would suggest you simply write "...Mr. Gilani that [sic] he did not believe..." (you may have already known that, but I decided to open my fat mouth/fingers anyway)

Comment: ＠Snumpy. I didn’t know the word and usage of sic. Per your advice, I consulted it for Wikipedia, which gave me the definition: Sic in square brackets is an editing term used with quotations or excerpts. It means that's really how it appears in the original. Actually I gave inconvenience to answerers recently a couple of times by posting quotes without making it clear whether they are [sic] or processed (Even I was careless). Indication of [sic] prevents such a problem. Great learning. Thank you very much.

Comment: The writer accidentally a word out.

Comment: @snumpy: Are you sure that inserting '[sic]' is appropriate here? Isn't quoting enough? Or should one append "[sic]" after the entire quotation?

Comment: @Mitch *[sic]* is explicitly placed immediately after a mistake (whether misspelling, word omission or otherwise) to indicate to the reader that the mistake was in the original text/statement rather than a typo on your part.

Comment: @snumpy: yes..but I guess I just question the whole operation of "[sic]" (I'm being very literal minded here...what happens if you make a mistake with '[sic]'? what if '[sic]' is actually present in the text you are quoting? etc. These are similar issues with punctuation inside or outside of quotes.

Comment: @Mitch If you make a mistake (with or without *[sic]*), it's a mistake, and that's that.  If it is still in a state in which it can be corrected, it should be.  If *[sic]* is in the text you are quoting, then you leave it in, as the person you are directly quoting also noticed a mistake in what he has quoted.  *[sic]* is simply a device to save time/space to assure your reader you did not make a mistake.  If it troubles you that much, don't use it, and use the time and space to explicitly inform your reader of what is and is not mistaken in your quote.

Comment: @snumpy: in this particular case it is obvious what the mistake is and so easy to place the '[sic]'. what if (as could easily be the case here) the quoter _suspects_ a mistake but doesn't know where exactly, then what?

Comment: @Mitch then our hypothetical quoter should ask a question [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/), quoting the sentence and saying, "I'm trying to use this quote from *X* but am pretty sure there is a gramatical mistake somewhere.  Can someone tell me where the *[sic]* belongs or if I'm mistaken and it's actually correct?"

Comment: @ Mitch/ Snumpy. I think I'm repeating the same question as you are arguing. Regarding [sic], Oxford Advanced Learners’ Dictionary says: written after a word that you have copied from somewhere to show that you know that the word is wrongly. Another Dictionary simply says ‘append it after the text containing an error or doubtful part’. We Japanese place the wordママ - ‘mama’ meaning ‘as it is’ immediate after the erroneous or doubtful expression. Though I think the same rule applies here, should we put [sic] immediate after the word in question as Snumpy suggests, or after whole quoted text?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right: it is a simple error. The writer forgot a verb like *said* or *added* or something similar.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, I definitely think this is a typo or a simple mistake, we need a verb there.

> said
>
> stated
>
> asserted

Something to that effect.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed; a word is missing. The missing word may be completely intentional. Sometimes a writer will omit words in order to make identification of their own work simple in a situation where it is copied and pasted without attribution.

Comment: Interesting that they would do that!